# Using a CSV in javascript (as an array)

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm trying to use a CSV in JS as an array. Right now I'm using ajax like this:

```
//Uses ajax to pull CSV and also calls the two functions above    
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    //update CSV name to match your CSV
    var csv_name = "BIG_DATA.csv";
    $.ajax({
    url: csv_name,
    dataType: 'text',
    }).done((data) => {parserFunction(data); chartsFunction(); calendarFunc();})
});
```

This works on my web server when I put the CSV file in the same folder as the .js file, but when I do the same thing offline, it doesn't work. I get this error:

jquery.min.js:2 Failed to load file:///Users/Andrew/Desktop/Internship2018-master/BIG_DATA.csv: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are not allowed to access file from the local system in JavaScript. You need to host that file in your local or remote server to access it.

Comment: Makes sense. Still, I just tried it using Python's local host feature and I get this error 'BIG_DATA.csv:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (File not found)'

Comment: when I say Python feature, I mean this: 'python -m http.server'

Comment: You can use the file reader api. Webkit's will keep watching for changes Firefox won't.

Comment: FileReader worked for my purposes thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can put `overflow: hidden` on any element that has a scrollbar. It will then disappear. To remove all scrollbars, you can do this:

```
*{
    overflow:hidden;
}
```